# google checkout with appengine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-checkout

I am trying to get my website to have a simple checkout flow where the person is able to create an account and pay for the product. I want to record this in the datastore so that the account gets created only when the payment has gone through and the person should be able to get back to the profile/personal page once done. I looked at gchecky and tried to find the google appengine compatible version but haven't been able get anything. Not even any sample code or tutorial using python.
Any help or alternatives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We based our version on the google checkout from this project http://code.google.com/p/chippysshop/

there is a listener and it creates the order when it receives a confirmation back from Google

works fine for us.